# Getting 'Traffic Source' in universal analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

How to get Traffic source data in universal analytics?

I'm trying the following code in firebug console:-

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var src = tracker.get('campaignSource');
  console.log(src);
});
```

But it always logs 'undefined'.

The field 'campaignMedium' also returns 'undefined'.

But I get correct values for some fields like 'clientId' or 'screenResolution' or 'language'.

Is there some other process to get these infromation?

P.S: I'm using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#trafficsources for reference of field names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can because campaign info is all stored server-side. The reason you're able to get the value of the fields for 'clientId', 'screenResolution' and 'language' is that they are stored client-side.

If you wanted to get the campaign source, etc., you'd have to create your own cookie and store the campaign values there.

Comment: To store it in cookie we have to obtain it from somewhere. How do we obtain these values?

Comment: For now, "old" Google Analytics and reading values from cookie will work, but I would NOT recommend implementing it only because of this. You can either store referrer (search engines, websites etc.) or UTM parameters if present.

Comment: Save with `$.cookie('utm_source', $.getQuery()['utm_source'])`. Access later with `console.log($.cookie('utm_source'));`. Requires jquery-cookie and jquery-parsequery

Answer (score 1):

As Blexy suggested, with UA it's better to rely on your own cookie for tracking traffic sources. Try this project: https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative